# How to get the parameter value from an ajax call in the page controller?

Tags: 8, javascript

I have the following js code according to es6.

```
(($, Drupal) => {
  Drupal.behaviors.mymodule = {
    attach: () => {
      document.querySelectorAll("a").forEach(element => {
        element.addEventListener("click", e => {
            fetch("/mypath", {
              method: "POST",
              body: JSON.stringify({
                path: $(this).attr("href")
              }),
            });
        });
      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

and in the page controller:

```
public function content(\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request) {
  $path = $request->request->get('path');
}
```

But I am not getting the path. Can someone tell me how to get the path in my page controller?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to use `fetch()` when your code is based on jQuery? There a plenty of examples using `$.ajax()` for POST requests:

*/core/modules/quickedit/js/quickedit.es6.js*

```
  $.ajax({
    url: Drupal.url('quickedit/metadata'),
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      'fields[]': fieldIDs,
      'entities[]': entityIDs,
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success(results) {
      // Store the metadata.
      _.each(results, (fieldMetadata, fieldID) => {
        Drupal.quickedit.metadata.add(fieldID, fieldMetadata);
      });

      callback(fieldElementsWithoutMetadata);
    },
  });
```

*/core/modules/quickedit/src/QuickEditController.php*

```
  public function metadata(Request $request) {
    $fields = $request->request->get('fields');
    ...
```

To make PHP accept POST parameters you need to specify the correct request headers. Default in `$.ajax()` is the contentType `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

So when using `fetch()` start with this:

```
fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
```

To get on par with $.ajax() you might need to tweak fetch() a little more or wait until core decides to change the Ajax libraries from jQuery to pure Javascript.